# LINQ to SQL: there was an error in a part of the date format

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, windows-phone-7

I have an application where I want to find the distinct available months that are available in a given year. However, with the query below I get the error message

> There was an error in a part of the date format. [ Expression (if known) = ]

when I try to execute the following query:

```
IQueryable<DateTime> availableMonths =
    (from item in database.IntakeItems
     where item.Timestamp >= statsYearStart
             && item.Timestamp <= statsYearEnd
     select new DateTime(1, item.Timestamp.Month, 1))
     .Distinct()
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.Month);
```

The `statsYearStart` and `statsYearEnd` are created in a property-setter and contain valid DateTime when the query is executed:

```
statsYearEnd = new DateTime(value, 12, 31);
statsYearStart = new DateTime(value, 1, 1);
```

The database is created via a code-first approach using EntityFramework. The column for item.Timestamp is defined as:

```
private DateTime timestamp;

[Column]
public DateTime Timestamp
{
    get
    {
        return timestamp;
    }
    set
    {
        if (timestamp != value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging();
            timestamp = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to LINQ and EF, so let me know if you need additional information. At first I suspected that this could be because of a localization issue (the Application), however I'm not using `.ToString` on any of the `DateTime`s. What might cause the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are setting the `Year` of the `DateTime` to `1` and I believe that the minimum date for EF is

```
1/1/1753
```

Comment: Awesome, that's it. Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: @ChrisK Glad I could help :) when you can, please accept it if you are happy with the answer so that the question can be closed

Comment: I will as soon as the 10 Minutes are over :)

Comment: +1. I don't think EF has that minimum date itself, but rather some databases do as a way to get around the question of what to do about 1752-09-03 through 1752-09-13, which didn't happen in Great Britain or her colonies (including those that would later become the United States) as that's when they changed from the Julian to Gregorian calendar. SQLServer has this limit on its `datetime` datatype, though `datetime2` gets around it by using proleptic Gregorian (that is, by pretending the Gregorian was in use for all time, so the day before 1752-09-14 is called 1752-09-13 rather than 1752-09-02.